# Boolean Satisfiability: Probabilistic Method

Tags: combinatorics, probabilistic-method

I'm currently take a non-credit course in extremal combinatorics and this question is given as an exercise for the Lovasz Local Lemma. It follows directly from the symmetric version of the lemma if there are exactly $k$ literals in each clause. I was wondering if proving this question would require the generalized version of the lemma.

A hint for the solution would be really appreciated.

[image: The Problem]